# Regex Matching shortest match instead of longest

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write regex but having trouble making it work for some cases. Here is the regex

```
(\/[ABCGIKLNPRSUV])?(\/RC-[A-Z0-9]{2,6})?
```

The matches could be one of the following

- /R/RC-ABC123
- /R
- /RC-ABC123

The above regex works for /R and /R/RC-ABC123 but not /RC-ABC123. For /RC-ABC123, it keeps matching against the first group instead of the second group and only takes /R as the matched component.

How can I make it work for all the cases.  Also, the above expression is only a part of the full expression i.e. there could be another (third) group after RC-ABC123. But want to get it working for these 2 groups first.

**Update**
The ?? seems to work in regex101 but not in java. I get 2 groups but with null values for /R/RC-ABC123 using the following code

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(/[A-Z])??(/RC-[A-Z0-9]{2,6})?");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("/R/RC-ABC12345");
    if(matcher.find()) {
        for(int i=1; i<= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Group("+i+") = " + matcher.group(i));
        }
    }else {
        System.out.println("Pattern does not match");
    }
```

Comment: FYI only, it matches the first optional group so it's done at that point. Have you tried adding anchors `^` and `$`, so it *must* match a complete entry?

Comment: Try [`(/R(?:C-[A-Z0-9]{2,6})?)(/[ABCGIKLNPSUV])?`](https://regex101.com/r/xA9fA2/1). Note in Java regex, you do not need to escape `/`.

Comment: You can make an optional item non-greedy by using `??` instead of `?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution does not handle /S/RC-ABC123, which should be handled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the first optional group non-greedy with `??`, so it will prefer to match the second group if it has a choice.

```
(/[ABCGIKLNPRSUV])??(/RC-[A-Z0-9]{2,6})?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vL0kU3/1)

Comment: Thank you..but looks like you are using /g option. If you remove that /g option, it does not work. If I am using something like Java, I don't think there is an option to specify /g. Moreover, I am invoking a library that was written by someone which just takes the pattern and the string to be matched and spits out the groups.

Comment: The `g` modifier is needed in regex101.com to see multiple matches in the demo. You don't need it if you're just matching one string at a time.

Comment: Well it does not work in java, as I get 2 groups but with null values. However, based on the regex101 result, I will accept the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work. According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html Java supports the `??` non-greedy optional quantifier.

Comment: I don't use Java myself, so I can't easily test this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the `R` is taken from the first optional group character class, as it allows the first group match at the same location as the second group.

You may create a non-capturing sub-group inside the first capturing group to handle this situation and "temper" the `R` branch with a negative lookahead, so that it only matched `R`s that are not followed with `C-` and then 2 to 6 uppercase ASCII letters or digits:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(/(?:R(?!C-[A-Z0-9]{2,6})|[ABCGIKLNPSUV]))?(/RC-[A-Z0-9]{2,6})?");
```

See [Java demo](http://ideone.com/RUOuKz). Test results:

```
/RC-ABC123    ->  { Group(1) = null, Group(2) = /RC-ABC123 }
/R/RC-ABC123  ->  { Group(1) = /R, Group(2) = /RC-ABC123 }
/R            ->  { Group(1) = /R, Group(2) = null }
/S/RC-ABC123  ->  { Group(1) = /S, Group(2) = /RC-ABC123 }
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(/(?:R(?!C-[A-Z0-9]{2,6})|[ABCGIKLNPSUV]))?` - Optional Group 2:

  - `/` - a forward slash
  - `(?:R(?!C-[A-Z0-9]{2,6})|[ABCGIKLNPSUV])` - 2 alternatives in a non-capturing group:

    - `R(?!C-[A-Z0-9]{2,6})` - `R` that is not followed with `C-` and then 2 to 6 uppercase ASCII letters or digits
    - `|` - or
    - `[ABCGIKLNPSUV]` - 1 of these letters
- `(/RC-[A-Z0-9]{2,6})?` - Optional Group 2:

  - `/RC-` - literal substring `/RC-`
  - `[A-Z0-9]{2,6}` - 2 to 6 uppercase ASCII letters or digits.